# intersect command with NA (or same values)

Tags: r, matrix, intersection

I want to use the intersect command, but I have two times "NA" in two rows, so that it does not work.
 Here is my attempt:

```
A<-matrix(c(4,9,5,3,1,7,NA,15,NA,6,9,3,9,5,1,11,3,8,NA,9,7,NA,21,17),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
B<-matrix(c(7,1,5,9,4,3,NA,NA,6,3,9,15,8,3,11,1,5,9,9,NA,7,NA,17,21),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
order.A <- t(apply(A, 1, order))
A.new <- matrix(A[cbind(c(row(A)), c(order.A))], ,6)
G1<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=3)
G2<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=3)
for (i in 1:4){
 G1[i,]<-intersect(B[i,],A.new[i,1:3])
 G2[i,]<-intersect(B[i,],A.new[i,4:6])
}
```

I want to sort G2 so that the "NA" appear at the end of the rows: It should look like this:

```
      G1         G2
 (1 4 3)     (7 5 9)
 (6 3 9)  (15 NA NA)
 (3 1 5)    (8 11 9)
(9 7 17)  (21 NA NA)
```

Comment: What's the input for `G2` (= you may want to post the result of `dput(G2)`) and the exptected output for it? The `for` loop throws an error: _"Error in G2[i, ] <- intersect(B[i, ], A.new[i, 4:6]) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"_  because `intersect(B[4,],A.new[4,4:6])` does not work with your data.

Comment: Yes, the intersect command does not work, because of the NA. Is there perhaps a additional command like "na.rm" or "NA=T" so that R ignores the NA or put it at the end of the rows?

Comment: The intersect command works: `intersect(A.new[4, 4:6], B[4, ])`. In the perfect intersect world, what should the result of that command be? Do you want `\`length<-\`(intersect(A.new[4, 4:6], B[4, ]), 3)`?

Comment: okay, you are right (the intersect command works). But why I got the error message:  "Error in G2[i, ] <- intersect(B[i, ], A.new[i, 4:6]) : number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length"?

Comment: Because `G2[4,]` is of length `3`, and `intersect(A.new[4, 4:6], B[4, ])` is of length `2`.

Comment: Okay, now I understand your comment above. Thank you. Perhaps, do you have any idea how I can get my desired solution?

Comment: The intersect command works: intersect(A.new[4, 4:6], B[4, ]). In the perfect intersect world, what should the result of that command be? Do you want `length<-`(intersect(A.new[4, 4:6], B[4, ]), 3)

Comment: But then I got this error message: Unexpected ',' in "(intersect(A.new[4, 4:6], B[4, ])," Somehow it does not work.

Comment: Thank you ver much. Now it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
A<-matrix(c(4,9,5,3,1,7,  NA,15,NA,6,9,3,  9,5,1,11,3,8,  NA,9,7,NA,21,17),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
B<-matrix(c(7,1,5,9,4,3,  NA,NA,6,3,9,15,  8,3,11,1,5,9,  9,NA,7,NA,17,21),4,6,byrow=TRUE)
order.A <- t(apply(A, 1, order))
A.new <- matrix(A[cbind(c(row(A)), c(order.A))], ,6)
G1<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=3)
G2<-matrix(nrow=4,ncol=3)
for (i in 1:4){
  G1[i,]<-intersect(B[i,],A.new[i,1:3])
  G2[i,]<-`length<-`(intersect(A.new[i, 4:6], B[i, ]), 3)
}
G2
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    5    7    9
# [2,]   15   NA   NA
# [3,]    8    9   11
# [4,]   21   NA   NA
```

The variation will fill in additional `NA`s, if the length of the result of the `intersect` command is `<3`.